# Polynomial rings over rational numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

We know that polynomial rings over $\mathbb{Q}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. It has a well-known basis $1, x, x^2,\ldots$ but can we classify all bases?

Comment: For @Rahman: What do you mean by classifying all bases?

Comment: Note that every basis has $\aleph_0$ members, but that means that there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ different bases. To see this note that for every $A\subseteq\mathbb N$ the set $\{x^n\mid n\in A\}\cup\{x^n+1\mid n\notin A\}$ is also a basis, and every $A$ generates a different basis.

Comment: I wonder whether this vector space has another maximal independent set except for standard basis.

Comment: Asaf just showed you a way to construct uncountably many different bases. Furthermore, it is straightforward to extend **any** finite independent set into a basis....

Answer (score 1):

To answer a question posted in the comments under the question: there are lots of other bases.  If you take one polynomial of each degree, for degrees $0,1,2,3,\ldots$, that's always a basis (take degree $0$ to mean nonzero constant polynomials).  You can find a set of four third-degree polynomials that spans the set of all polynomials of degree $\le 3$, so you don't need one of each degree.  (For example, the difference between two of them could be $x^2$, and between two others could be $x$, etc.)  A basis must have $\le n+1$ polynomials of degree $n$ or less (any more would make it linearly dependent since the dimension of that subspace is $n+1$.

A linearly independent set of polynomials is a basis if for infinitely many $n$ the number of members of the set having degree $\le n$ is $n+1$.  I'm guessing that that sufficient condition is also a necessary condition.  More later, maybe, . . . .